# firebase - Log in again after the user has registered for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi everyone I have such a problem,
After a user signs up for my site, for the first time, I want to log in with the user one more time.

I want that after he registers, connect again.

I tried to do it asynchronously, but it does not always work, sometimes I try to log in before the user is registers, I do not know why it does not work.

I want there to be a login only after registration, to force it.

```js
  handleSubmit = async () => {
    
    const newUserData = {
      email: 'test@mail.com',
      password: '123456',
      confirmPassword: '123456',
      handle: 'test'
    };

    await signupUser(newUserData);
    await signinChat(newUserData);
  }
```

```js
export const signupUser = (newUserData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post('/signup', newUserData)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};



//basically call to this function to signup

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle,
  };

  db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return res.status(400).json({ handle: "this handle is already taken" });
      } else {
        return firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password);
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      userId = data.user.uid;
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((idToken) => {
      token = idToken;
      const userCredentials = {
        handle: newUser.handle,
        email: newUser.email,
      };
      const userPreferences = {
        handle: newUser.handle
      };

      return db.doc(`/users/${newUser.handle}`).set(userCredentials);
    })
    .then(() => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      if (err.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email is already is use" });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ general: "Something went wrong, please try again" });
      }
    });
};
```

```js
export const signinChat = (user) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        firebase.auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                const name = `${user.handle}`;
                currentUser.updateProfile({
                    displayName: name,
                })
                    .then(() => {
                        db.collection('users')
                            .doc(data.user.displayName)
                            .update({
                                isOnline: true,
                            })
                            .then(() => {
                                const loggedInUser = {
                                    handle: user.handle,
                                    uid: data.user.uid,
                                    email: user.email
                                }
                                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(loggedInUser));
                                console.log('User logged in successfully...!');
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

When I try to connect a second time, sometimes it does not work, for example:
image to show the error:

[image]

Comment: You shared quite some code, but I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you summarize that in a single-sentence question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, after a user makes a signup, I want to make a signin after that.

Comment: When you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, the newly created user is already signed in.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Hi thank you for the reply first of all, right after `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, it login automatically .      

But I also want to access `currentUser`, and I could not do it according to my code. That's why I want to login again .        

According to my code it is not possible to access `currentUser`, in nodejs. That's why I login once again after signing up. To access `currentUser`. But I do not understand why sometimes it gets stuck for me,  but I do not understand why, because I used promises.     I would love if you could help me with that

Comment: That's a whole long description again, and I'm having a hard time parsing it into a single, isolated problem.  I with I could help better, but there's just too much unclarity here. I recommend reproducing the problem in isolation with minimal code, as explained in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That maximizes the chances someone can help.